# JColorChooser front end changing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, color-picker

I'm trying to understand why `JColorChooser` changes in appearance when my application is run from the IDE (Eclipse) or from a Jar file (created by an ant script).
This is the panel when run from the IDE:
[image: IDE JColorChooser]

and this is the panel when run from the executable jar:
[image: Jar JColorChooser]

The color chooser is created with:

```
final JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser(Color.WHITE);
colorChooser.setPreviewPanel(new JPanel());
```

The VM arguments set are the same too:

```
 -Dsun.java2d.opengl=True -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true
```

I just can't understand why the panels are different when run from different locations. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Probably because you're not using the same Java versions.

Comment: It's the same machine. Only one version of java installed (`1.6u29`)

Answer (score 3):

The extra [custom chooser panels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html) are probably coming from a JAR that's in the IDE's class path, but not in the `Class-Path` of the JAR's manifest. You should look for the stray JAR in one of your platform's [`java.ext.dirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html) or `java.class.path`.